# In Web Garden Mode, how process Id is maintained for all major browsers except opera?

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, web-garden

I was testing sessions behavior in *Web Garden* mode.

Why do all major browsers use only one process (on server) except *Opera*? and how is it done?

Here is very simple web application:

Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id);
}
```

Markup:

```
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

Every time I click on button in *Opera* I get different numbers (depending on Worker processes count), which is normal. But in *Chrome*, I always get same process id.

Comment: You said: > Why do all major browsers use only one process The clients (browsers) know nothing about the server processes.

Comment: So Chrome isn't doing the postback? I don't see any Click handler.

Comment: Button does not require click handler to generate __DoPostBack. Browsers automatically rises Postback for this type of input element.

Comment: Ok. It should be "Why do all major browsers use only one process on server".

Comment: No, there is no direct relationship between the clients and the servers. At all.

Comment: I didn't said there is direct relationship. I'm not very good at English so maybe I didn't said exactly what I wanted to say. But I'm sure you understand what is the question.

Comment: No, I don't. There will be no consistent correlation between processes and what's happening on the browser.

Comment: No, the Browsers do not, the Javascript raises it.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Well... Just add this element <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" /> and look at the html source... 
You will see <form method="post"... not any JavaScript

Comment: So if it's javascript which rises postback, we can say, this javascript is generated by browser (Because there is no javascript in source). So in this case, browser rises postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made something wrong here and there is not sticky to browser process on web garden.

I have made some time ago the same tests and I never face this issue. I do not know the exactly mechanism, on how the asp.net is select what process will get the next request, but is not stick on the browser.

### Some more

Web garden is when you use on the same computer/server/pool more than one process to proceed each client requests.

The `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id` show what process is actual run the page you ask. I am not sure how the asp.net select what process will be selected to run the next request, probably have to do with the availability of each one, and the threads of each one run.

How ever did not have to do with the client and the calling browser data. So if you get the same or different ids, have to do with the load of the server, maybe the cache of the page on client, but for sure not have to do with the browser.

Comment: Can Connection: Keep-Alive header do some trick? http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1419402

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze I do not like to be negative because I do not know how asp.net give the processes. I only say you that in my test on all browsers (mozilla, ie, chrome, opera, safari) and on many systems that I have check I see the same results and not different as you say.